# How to understand Heisenberg time in random matrix theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, eigenvalue, chaos-theory, matrix-model

Recently, from few papers, I have encountered the word 'Heisenberg time' $t_{\text{H}}$ which is an inverse of a mean level spacing $\Delta(\hat{\mathcal{H}})$ of a finite system Hamiltonian $\hat{\mathcal{H}}$. Though its mathematical definition is given, I couldn't find the physical meaning of it. Is it ok to understand as a least time needed for a system to distinguish an average energy difference of $\Delta(\hat{\mathcal{H}})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have some another probe system which is coupled to your finite system. Then up to a time $t_{H}$ your probe will not experience the discreteness of the spectrum. That is, up to a time $t_{H}$ the probe will think that your system has continuous spectrum.

Put in other words, up to a time $t_{H}$ the probe will think that it interacts with an infinite quantum environment, whose consinuous spectral density is a smoothed verstion of the actual discrete spectrum.

After the time $t_{H}$ the probe will 'notice' that the system is finite. In the simplest cases, this means that some kind of reflected wave will come to the probe.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).